# Change font size for Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I'm using the Bootstrap table functionality which is great but I cannot seem to change the font size.

I'm following the example at https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#options/loading-font-size.html#view-source but whatever I change the size to, it has no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Bootstrap and Boostrap Table -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="home">
        <div>
            <table id="btTable" class = "table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="fieldA" data-sortable="true">Field A</th>
                    <th data-field="fieldB" data-sortable="true">Field B</th>
                    <th data-field="fieldC" data-sortable="true">Field C</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script defer>
            let data = [
                {
                    "fieldA": "purple",
                    "fieldB": "minivan",
                    "fieldC": 7,
                },
                {
                    "fieldA": "red",
                    "fieldB": "hatchback",
                    "fieldC": 26,
                }]
            var table = $("#btTable")
            $(function() {
                table.bootstrapTable({
                    data: data,
                    loadingFontSize: "30px"
                })
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: LoadingFontSize only changes the font of the loadingtest. Are you trying to change the text size for all rows inside the table? If so, did you try simply using CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the styling by using plain javascript. I add only this in your javascript code:

```js
            var tableStyle = document.querySelector('table');            
            tableStyle.classList.add('fs30');
```

And this css class:

```css
.fs30 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Then you have full control to change every element in you table.

```js
          let data = [
                {
                    "fieldA": "purple",
                    "fieldB": "minivan",
                    "fieldC": 7,
                },
                {
                    "fieldA": "red",
                    "fieldB": "hatchback",
                    "fieldC": 26,
                }]
          
            var tableStyle = document.querySelector('table');            
            tableStyle.classList.add('fs30');
            var table = $("#btTable")
            $(function() {
                table.bootstrapTable({
                    data: data,                    
                })
            })
```

```css
.fs30 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
    <head>
        <!-- Bootstrap and Boostrap Table -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="home">
        <div>
            <table id="btTable" class = "table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="fieldA" data-sortable="true">Field A</th>
                    <th data-field="fieldB" data-sortable="true">Field B</th>
                    <th data-field="fieldC" data-sortable="true">Field C</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            </table>
        </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct it won't change the font size of your table content as you are trying to change the font size of Loading text.
Try changing value of css font size like example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Bootstrap and Boostrap Table -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="home">
        <div>
            <table id="btTable" class = "table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="fieldA" data-sortable="true">Field A</th>
                    <th data-field="fieldB" data-sortable="true">Field B</th>
                    <th data-field="fieldC" data-sortable="true">Field C</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script defer>
            let data = [
                {
                    "fieldA": "purple",
                    "fieldB": "minivan",
                    "fieldC": 7,
                },
                {
                    "fieldA": "red",
                    "fieldB": "hatchback",
                    "fieldC": 26,
                }]
            var table = $("#btTable")
            $(function() {
                table.bootstrapTable({
                    data: data,
                    loadingFontSize: "60px"
                }).css('font-size', '30px')
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```